Using Polars expressions to apply `eval()` to a column
I would like to achieve the following via Polars expressions, as opposed to mapping the elements row-by-row, but I have not been able to figure out a way.
import polars

def foo():
    return 1 + 1

def bar():
    return 1 + 1

def baz():
    return 2 + 2

exprs = 1_000_000 * [
    "foo() == bar()",
    "bar() == baz()",
    "foo() == baz()",
    "foo() > bar()",
    "bar() < baz()",
    "foo() != baz()",
]

df = polars.DataFrame({"exprs": exprs})

df.with_columns(
    polars.col("exprs").map_elements(
        lambda x: eval(x), return_dtype=polars.datatypes.Boolean
    )
)

shape: (6_000_000, 1)
┌───────┐
│ exprs │
│ ---   │
│ bool  │
╞═══════╡
│ true  │
│ false │
│ false │
│ false │
│ true  │
│ …     │
│ false │
│ false │
│ false │
│ true  │
│ true  │
└───────┘

The issue being that foo() and bar() are non-trivial and so map_elements() takes some time to complete since the DataFrame is large.

So you want a column with 1 million true values? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Why not exprs = 1_000_000 * [foo() == bar()] then?

No, this is just an example. The output could be anything, depending on the expressions in the column.

Polars has native computations, which operate in Rust, and then Python for everything that can't be expressed in Rust. Python’s eval definitely can't be expressed in Rust, so you're stuck doing it in Python. Having strings you want to eval seems pretty unusual.

Yeah I thought I might be out of luck but figured it's worth asking. I know it's unusual however I am given a set of data validation rules (which I have no control over) as a .csv containing expressions like foo() != baz() and I am not sure how else to process them.

At the very least you could build a hash map of strings so that you only have to compute each expression once (assuming they're pure). If you wanted to go deeper you could parse the expressions into two functions and a comparison (if they all look like that) and then cache the function calls

Are foo, bar, baz really unrelated to some data in a df? If so, I'm not sure what polars can do for you. In any event, you shouldn't rerun each function for each comparison. Just save each function's output to a variable and then do the comparisons. Just based on this example, you have 12M function calls when you only need 3.

I think eval can be avoided altogether. This is assuming that:

your functions are pure and don't have parameters (which is consistent with your example)
the string expressions you want to evaluate are simple comparisons like in your examples

On your issue of foo() and bar() being non-trivial and map_elements() taking some time to complete since the DataFrame is large - as Dean says, save the result in a variable, or as BallpointBen says, evaluate them once so they can be put in a dictionary and looked up. Both avoid repeated evaluation of the functions.
And giving this suggestion from BallpointBen a go

If you wanted to go deeper you could parse the expressions into two functions and a comparison (if they all look like that) and then cache the function calls

I find that python does have many options like this, that are possible before you need to reach for eval
import operator

import polars as pl
pl.__version__ # 1.2.1

def foo():
    return 1 + 1

def bar():
    return 1 + 1

def baz():
    return 2 + 2


exprs = 1_000_000 * [
    "foo() == bar()",
    "bar() == baz()",
    "foo() == baz()",
    "foo() > bar()",
    "bar() < baz()",
    "foo() != baz()",
]
df = pl.DataFrame({"exprs": exprs})

# Map from string representation to operator function
# Add more operators to this map if needed
operator_map = {
    '==': operator.eq,
    '!=': operator.ne,
    '>': operator.gt,
    '<': operator.lt,
    '>=': operator.ge,
    '<=': operator.le,
}

# Map functions names to return values
# The non-trivial functions are evaluated once here, which avoids repeated work
# If this needs to be more dynamically created, use the inspect module
# Or if all functions are known, you can hardcode them. E.g., {"foo": foo()}
func_map = {
    k: v() for k, v in locals().items()
    if callable(v) and not k.startswith("_")
}


# Regex from "foo() == bar()" -> {"lhs: "foo", "op: "==", "rhs": "bar"}
# Parse the string expression into its parts
# first capturing group: "lhs" -> one or more word characters
# `()` followed by optional whitespace character
# second capturing group: "op" -> one or two of !=<>
# optional whitespace character
# third capturing group: "rhs" -> same as first group
expr_pattern = "(?<lhs>\w+)\(\)\s?(?<op>[!=<>]{1,2})\s?(?<rhs>\w+)"
groups = pl.col("exprs").str.extract_groups(expr_pattern)

# Only calculate the unique string expressions, and then join back
# This is much faster than calculating them all, due to intensiveness of regex matching
# It is good for low cardinality data like in the example
(
    df
    .unique()
    .with_columns(
        # The first three columns selected are just for demonstration
        lhs=groups.struct.field("lhs").replace_strict(func_map),
        op=groups.struct.field("op"),
        rhs=groups.struct.field("rhs").replace_strict(func_map),
        # You only really need the result column
        result=pl.coalesce(
            pl.when(groups.struct.field("op") == op_name)
            .then(
                op_func(
                    groups.struct.field("lhs").replace_strict(func_map),
                    groups.struct.field("rhs").replace_strict(func_map),
                )
            )
            # Only loops over 6 items, and coalesce will likely
            # parralelise the evaluation
            for op_name, op_func in operator_map.items()
        )
    )
    .join(df, on="exprs")
)

shape: (6_000_000, 5)
┌────────────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ exprs          ┆ lhs ┆ op  ┆ rhs ┆ result │
│ ---            ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ str            ┆ i64 ┆ str ┆ i64 ┆ bool   │
╞════════════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ foo() == bar() ┆ 2   ┆ ==  ┆ 2   ┆ true   │
│ bar() == baz() ┆ 2   ┆ ==  ┆ 4   ┆ false  │
│ foo() == baz() ┆ 2   ┆ ==  ┆ 4   ┆ false  │
│ foo() > bar()  ┆ 2   ┆ >   ┆ 2   ┆ false  │
│ bar() < baz()  ┆ 2   ┆ <   ┆ 4   ┆ true   │
│ …              ┆ …   ┆ …   ┆ …   ┆ …      │
│ bar() == baz() ┆ 2   ┆ ==  ┆ 4   ┆ false  │
│ foo() == baz() ┆ 2   ┆ ==  ┆ 4   ┆ false  │
│ foo() > bar()  ┆ 2   ┆ >   ┆ 2   ┆ false  │
│ bar() < baz()  ┆ 2   ┆ <   ┆ 4   ┆ true   │
│ foo() != baz() ┆ 2   ┆ !=  ┆ 4   ┆ true   │
└────────────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴────────┘

As an aside, you can probably speed up your eval code, by not calling the function more than once, and minimising the number of eval calls that are made.
# As above, use the inspect module or hardcode like {"foo": foo()} if needed
func_map = {
    k: str(v()) for k, v in locals().items()
    if callable(v) and not k.startswith("_")
}

(
    df
    # Call unique, so each expression only needs to be evaluated once
    # Good for low cardinality data like in the example
    .unique()
    .with_columns(
        result=pl.col("exprs")
        # Replace function name with its value, and replace parentheses with empty string
        # replace_many will do them all at once
        .str.replace_many(list(func_map.keys()) + ["()"], list(func_map.values()) + [""])
        .map_elements(lambda x: eval(x), return_dtype=pl.Boolean)
    )
    .join(df, on="exprs")
)


Thanks for the answer. The functions are not pure unfortunately (sorry I didn't include that in my question). And they could be arbitrarily nested. e.g. foo(bar(baz(x, y, z))) == baz(foo(), y, z) AND baz(bar(), a, b) > 5.

In that case, unless you want to parse the strings into Polars expressions, I'm out of ideas and think eval with map_elements would be your best bet. On large data with lower cardinality, I think it would be faster to do a unique to ensure each string expression is only evaluated once, then join back to the original data, rather than eval each row. Benchmark on your own data.
